# Sort multidimensional XML with PHP by date

Tags: php, xml, sorting, simplexml

I can't find an exact duplicate of this question, as my nodes are numerical keys.

I need to sort this xml by date - newest first:

```
[article] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [value] => some value
                [date] => 2012-08-13 18:54:09
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [id] => some more value
                [date] => 2012-08-09 10:24:06
            )

        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [id] => another value
                [date] => 2012-08-11 20:45:44
            )
     )
```

How can I best do that - possibly WITHOUT turning the XML into a PHP array and sorting it then.

Comment: Both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940042/sort-multidimensional-xml-with-php-by-date and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998722/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-xml-file seems fine to me. If you don't want the `xsort()` and `array_multisort()`, then just use `usort()` with a custom function comparing the date, no?

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work as the arrays are xml objects

Answer (score 0):

From your sample, it looks like you have an array of objects already, so `usort` would work fine.

The callback would look something like this:

```
function compare_node_dates($a, $b)
{
    return
        strtotime((string)$b->date)
        -
        strtotime((string)$a->date);
}
```

However, if your outermost variable isn't actually an array, there is no way I'm aware of doing this without creating an array, sorting that, and using that to construct brand new XML.