# sorting the table fields using simple XML and xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a xml file loaded simplexml, and I need to sort the fields by price, or by author or title. How could I do? Is it ok do it using xpath or another way? I saw a similar example here, but I have not very clear

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Cervantes]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[El Quijote]]></titulo>
        <precio>30€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Calderón de la Barca]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[La vida es sueño]]></titulo>
        <precio>25€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Garcilaso de la vega]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Egoglas]]></titulo>
        <precio>15€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Raymond Carver]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Catedral]]></titulo>
        <precio>16€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[George Orwell]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[1984]]></titulo>
        <precio>10€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Fidor Dostoyevski]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Crimen y Castigo]]></titulo>
        <precio>35€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Juan Ponce]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Cronica de la intervencion]]></titulo>
        <precio>25€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Yukio Mishima]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Confesiones de una mascara]]></titulo>
        <precio>22€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Elfriede Jelinek]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Deseo]]></titulo>
        <precio>20€</precio>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <autor><![CDATA[Bram Stoker]]></autor>
        <titulo><![CDATA[Dracula]]></titulo>
        <precio>18€</precio>
    </libro>
</root>
```

PHP

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/libros.xml');
$sum = 0;
$h = "<table>";
$h .= "<tr>";
$h .= "<td><a href='#'  id='ordAut'><img src='img/up_down.png' /></a></td><td><a href='#'  id='ordTit'><img src='img/up_down.png' /></a></td><td><a href='#'  id='ordPre'><img src='img/up_down.png' /></a></td>";
$h .= "</tr>";
foreach ($xml->libro as $book) {
    $h .= "<tr>";
    $h .= "<td>".$book->autor."</td><td>".$book->titulo."</td><td>".$book->precio."</td>";
    $h .= "</tr>";
    $sum += $book->precio;
}

$h .= "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">sum:</td><td>$sum</td></tr></table>";
echo $h;
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998722/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-xml-file - the accepted answer should do the trick!

Comment: good, just update your question if you need help.

Comment: jal, I got your comment that you had updated your question, but it linked to a page that said: question had been removed by author ?

Comment: @michi Sorry I made a mistake. I wrote it again

Comment: @michi this example sorts a field only, what I need is to sort the entire table, for example sort author, title, price, by price ascending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your simplexml like this:

function `sort_obj_arr`written by [GZipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153350/gzipp) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119686/sorting-an-array-of-simplexml-objects)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$books = $xml->xpath("//libro");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($books);
echo "</pre>";

$field = 'precio';
sort_obj_arr($books,$field,SORT_DESC);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($books);
echo "</pre>";


function sort_obj_arr(& $arr, $sort_field, $sort_direction)
{
    $sort_func = function($obj_1, $obj_2) use ($sort_field, $sort_direction)
    {
        if ($sort_direction == SORT_ASC) {
            return strnatcasecmp($obj_1->$sort_field, $obj_2->$sort_field);
        } else {
            return strnatcasecmp($obj_2->$sort_field, $obj_1->$sort_field);
        }
    };
    usort($arr, $sort_func);
}
```

Live demo @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/QvLqIq

Answer (score 0):

i know it sounds dumb at first: but map the data in an array and use a custom array callback for `usort` 
if you want to do it *right right* you will develop something that is called a paginator, which takes care of limit the result displayed on the page and lets you use custom filters.

Comment: I used usort, but I had problems