# Rearrange XML nodes with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a dynamic banner with images/info that are saved in an XML file. I'm adding the option for the user to rearrange the images however they like (Jquery sortable) and once I get the new order (which countains the id attribute) I would like to rearrange without having to copy each node's infos and saving it again in the new order. For instance:

```
<banners>
 <banner id="1001">
  <infos...>
 </banner>
 <banner id="1003">
  <infos...>
 </banner>
 <banner id="900">
  <infos...>
 </banner>
</banners>
```

Say the user rearranged to 900, 1003, 1001. I would like to be able to get the nodes by the ID# and reposition them accordingly. Is there an easy way of doing that?

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) add a child `order` to every `<banner>`-node and (2) sort the xml by that child.

for (1): `$xml` is the simplexml-object, the order is stored in `$order`...

```
$order=array(900,1001,1003);

foreach ($xml->banner as $banner) {

    foreach ($order as $k => $v)
        if ($banner['id']==$v) $banner->addChild('order',$k);

}
```

for (2): sort xml by `order`:
see accepted answer in this post: [sorting the table fields using simple XML and xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604459/sorting-the-table-fields-using-simple-xml-and-xpath/15625514#15625514)

see live-demo @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/MdcT7B

Comment: thank you, I was just curious to see if addChild would carry over the whole <infos> from the banner with id=X. I will give this answer a try and post it on here in case it works.