# sorting simpleXML object

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I have a problem to sort array of `SimpleXMLElement` Object. The data is:

```
[ServiceHotel] => Array
(
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [@attributes] => Array
        (
          [availToken] => 0
        )
    )
  [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [@attributes] => Array
        (
          [availToken] => 1
        )
    )
  [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
          [availToken] => 2
        )
    )
  [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [@attributes] => Array
        (
          [availToken] => 3
        )
    )
)
```

I want to sort that data, order by `availToken` in PHP. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339726/sort-objectsimplexmlelement-php

Comment: thanks @rafael thats a solution