# Usort Date Xml PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting, date

I'm trying to order my XML by date but code doesn't work well.
Here is my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ('http://xml.dsautoestoque.com/?l=09086369000133');
$arr=array();
foreach($xml->veiculo as $aTask)
{
    $arr[]=$aTask;

}

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  $ad = new DateTime($a['cadastro']);
  $bd = new DateTime($b['cadastro']);

  if ($ad == $bd) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $ad > $bd ? 1 : -1;
});
```

I did like this

```
foreach($arr as $aTask)
{
    $data1 = $aTask->cadastro;
}
```

But is not returning by date, it is returning this
03/08/2015 18:22
24/11/2015 11:16
22/10/2015 17:36

Comment: show some sample dates, and check that DateTime is successfully parsing them. you're just assuming success right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting the table fields using simple XML and xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604459/sorting-the-table-fields-using-simple-xml-and-xpath)

Comment: i've tried a lot of examples but none of them worked well

Comment: I've just tried to use @michi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604459/sorting-the-table-fields-using-simple-xml-and-xpath  and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$a` and `$b` are of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and `$a['cadastro']` and `$b['cadastro']` are `null`.

So you are instantiating your DateTime's like this `new DateTime(null)` and that will match this line: `if ($ad == $bd) {` and your array will not get sorted.

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ('http://xml.dsautoestoque.com/?l=09086369000133');

$arr = array();
foreach ($xml->veiculo as $aTask) {
    $arr[] = $aTask;

}

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    $ad = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $a->cadastro->__toString());
    $bd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $b->cadastro->__toString());

    if ($ad == $bd) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $ad > $bd ? 1 : -1;
});
```